# Filter issue while using Search/Filter logic - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search, filter

I am struggling with my React Native App!!!! 
I have a simple Flatlist. 
I have a TextInput that has a filter option.
Click inside the TextInput. A dropdown of filter appears.

Click on that Filter it appears inside the TextInput.

Need some help in styling this!!! It should look somewhat like this. If not to this extent at least a box around it is fine.

[image]

I tried it with a Button - React Native elements. It's so so so frustrating. I cannot use any 3rd party libraries (company policy).

TextInput Code:

```
                      <Icon type='materialicons' name='search'  />    // search icon


                      <Button icon={<Icon name="check"/>}.  //my attempt to create a button around the filter 
                              type='clear' title ={val}
                              onPress={()=>{this.handleFilterIcon(false); this.setFilt(false)}}/>



                  <TextInput       // Text Input
                    value={value} 
                    placeholder='Search Here...'
                    onChangeText={(text)=>{this.handleSearch(text, true);this.renderDropDown(false)}}  
                    onTouchStart={()=>{this.setTempNotifications();this.renderDropDown(true)}}
                    style={{ height: 40, flex: 1}}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    selectTextOnFocus={true}
                    label='input'
                  />

                  <Icon type='materialicons' name='cancel' onPress={()=>{} /> // Clear Icon

                  <Button title='Cancel' 
                  buttonStyle={{backgroundColor:'#D3D3D3', borderColor: 'grey', borderRadius: 6 , borderWidth: 1, height: 40}}
                  onPress={()=>{} />   // Cancel button
```

Anyone please tell me the most efficient way to do this!!!

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you not able to filter or do you need help in styling the text that is entered into the field ?

Comment: Need help in Styling the text entered into the field. As soon as I click on "Hospital Authority" the text inside the input should be styled. Like a box/button around it (generally how we have Filters in our phone)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'm seeing is, since you don't have to use third party libraries is this:

1. Create a an empty label next to the input. Wrap these two with a div with `position:relative`
2. As soon as input is entered, put the same text in this label. Customise this label with styling: `position:absolute;background:grey...`

Just to give you some idea, here's an implementation in `JQuery`. You have to take this forward and ask specific question where you're struggling.

```js
function inputChange(val){
  $('label').text(val);
  $('input').val("");
}
```

```css
label{
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <input type="text" onchange="inputChange(this.value)"/>
  <label></label>
</div>
```

In React the same implementation could look something like this. You can create a file with this implementation, import in your App.js and see. Take this idea fowrward and change the styling and behaviours as per the need.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class CustomInputTextstyling extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            inputText: ""
        }

    }

    handleInputChange(e){
      this.setState({inputText: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        const wrapperDiv = {
            position: 'relative'
        }

        const label = {
            border:'1px solid',
            borderRadius: '5px',
            position: 'absolute',
            background: 'grey',
            left:'2px'
          }
        return (
            <div style={wrapperDiv}>
                <input type = "text" onBlur = {this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}></input>
                <label style={label}>{this.state.inputText}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CustomInputTextstyling;
```

Comment: Amaze!!! I'm really new at React Native :( struggling to convert this. I am using TextInput. where do I use <Label> ? Label is a separate element or a property of input?

Comment: @RakshaHegde See the updated answer. Implemented the same in React. Customise the styling as per your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul!!! I am just not able to use label with TextInput. Currently I store my text string in {value}. So <TextInput value={<label>........</label>}  /> something like this?

Comment: Nope we're not concerned about `TextInput` vale. We just want this `value` to be put inside `label` text. That's all

Comment: yes true we want value to be put inside label text. But I am not using Input. I am using TextInput and the label has to be displayed inside my TextInput.

Comment: Yup so what you need to do is this: the `text` that you're getting from `TextInput` in `this. handleSearch `, you need to set this in a state which will keep this value. The same `state` will be used to display the label text.

`this.state = {'myText': ''} //Constructor
handleSearch(text)=>{
  this.setState({'myText': text});
}` <label>{this.state.myText}</label>`